# Define multiple transition-property in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

When setting `transition-property` to `all`, it looks bad when zooming inside the browser window, because `width` and `height` properties are also being transitioned. When I only want `background` and `color`, I need to define it multi line, though:

```
transition-property: color, background;
transition-duration: 250ms;
```

This is bad, because I also have to do it for `-webkit-`, `-moz` and `-o-`. Instead I'm looking for something like this:

```
transition: [color and background] 250ms;
```

Is there any syntax for this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When using the `transition` shorthand with multiple transitions, you need to repeat the transition duration for each property, and separate each group of values with commas:

```
transition: color 250ms, background 250ms;
```

With prefixes, it looks like this:

```
-moz-transition: color 250ms, background 250ms;
-o-transition: color 250ms, background 250ms;
-webkit-transition: color 250ms, background 250ms;
transition: color 250ms, background 250ms;
```

Still a little repetitive, but at least it beats repeating `transition-property` and `transition-duration` for all the prefixes.

The shorthand syntax is described in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#transition-shorthand-property).

Comment: Simple :) It even gives me the option to use different durations for each property.